# Second key for Mazda5 2013 - programming vs cloning, 80 bit vs 40 bit

Tags: mazda, key

I have Mazda5 2013 with a single key, so I am trying to get a spare (at least one)

I have the part number ( **G2YA-76-2GXB** ) - dealer would charge $50 for the key plus $70 for the programming

There are few places where this key (exact part number) could be purchased for $10 - $15, but I am not sure if these keys would work or not:

1) Some keys are advertized as **40 bit** and some as **80 bit** (and they have same part number mentioned above)

2) According to sellers, some keys could be **cloned** by local locksmith (Ace hardware etc) and some could not (they must be **programmed** by the dealer)

could someone clarify these technical details?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the following on the [iKeyless website](https://ikeyless.com/vehicles/Mazda/MAZDA5/2013/1000391/), which indicates that you cannot program the key yourself and would need the dealer or a locksmith to do it.

> **Key Cutting/Programming:**  Programming instructions are not included.
>   This device requires cutting and programming by a dealership or
>   locksmith. The procedure takes only a few seconds to complete and many
>   dealerships will do it for free as a courtesy. If your dealer does
>   charge a fee, local locksmiths usually charge much less to remain
>   competitive.

Then on [locksmithcharley.com](http://locksmithcharley.com/transponder/mazda.shtml) it says:

> Their *(Mazda's)* newer "80-bit" offering 5913441 has "SA" stamped into the key.
>   Strattec's 5913441 and ILCO's H84PT 80-bit key blanks are backwards
>   compatible meaning that they will work in vehicles with a 40-bit
>   system. Keys cut on 40-bit blanks will not start vehicles requiring
>   80-bit keys.

Which leads me to believe that the your car, being "newer", would use an 80 bit key.  If your key has an "SA" stamped in it then you have an 80 bit key.

I think a 2013 Mazda 5 needs an 80 bit key based on information on [transponderisland.com](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&ved=0CD4QFjAC&url=http://www.transponderisland.com/mazda-flip-part-with-transponder-1727.html&ei=c9keUuPHIc3MigLO6YGQCw&usg=AFQjCNHdcaduU81lJ_xcBHLwn9wLBqzhTw&sig2=67B1-3CueoAX4HV4jwfy4g&bvm=bv.51495398,d.dGI&cad=rja).

> Mazda Flip Blade Part with Transponder Chip 80 Bit Related Products
>
> 2012 - 2013 Mazda Transponder Key 80 Bit - TI Brand
>
> 2012 - 2013 Mazda Transponder Key 80 Bit - TI Brand
>   2005 - 2013 Mazda 2 5 CX-7 CX-9 Remote Flip Key - 3B Remote Part BGBX1T478SKE125-01
>
> 2005 - 2013 Mazda 2 5 CX-7 CX-9 Remote Flip Key - 3B Remote Part BGBX1T478SKE125-01
>   2004 - 2010 Mazda Remote Flip Key Blade
>
> 2004 - 2010 Mazda Remote Flip Key Blade
>   2003 - 2013 Mazda Transponder Key MAZ24RT17
>
> 2003 - 2013 Mazda Transponder Key MAZ24RT17
>
> ...

I can't find if the "G2YA-76-2GXB" is 80 bit but, if that is the part number of the key that came with your car then I think it would be 80 bit since your Mazda 5 seems to be 80 bit compatible and the 40 bit keys aren't backwards compatible with 80 bit systems.

It sounds like an 80 bit key will work with either system and is therefore your safest bet.